# Tracking iOS memory usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

I am looking for a way to track iOS memory usage from within my app as accurately as possible. After many trials I end up with the following code:

```
uint64_t memory_usage (void) {
   task_vm_info_data_t vmInfo;
   mach_msg_type_number_t count = TASK_VM_INFO_COUNT;
   if (task_info(mach_task_self(), TASK_VM_INFO, (task_info_t) &vmInfo, &count) != KERN_SUCCESS) return -1;

   return vmInfo.internal;
}
```

When executed from a real device the value returned is in sync with the value reported by the Xcode debugger.

[image]

The behaviour that I cannot explain is when allocated memory reaches about 500MB the value returned by this function do not increase (it continue to report a value in the 450/450MB range) while the Xcode debugger continue to grow up until 1.3GB and then a memory warning is notified to my app.

The code I used to test this function is fired every 0.5 seconds from within an NSTimer with the following action:

```
- (void) checkMemory {
   uint64_t mem_usage = memory_usage();

   // allocate a 5MB buffer to test memory usage
   uint32_t buffer_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
   char *buffer = (char *)malloc(buffer_size);
   memset(buffer, 0, buffer_size);

   p[i++] = buffer;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: what if you try `vmInfo.phys_footprint`? It includes physical + swapped, so if that doesn't grow, would be really weird. If it does, then you know that `vmInfo.internal` doesn't grow, but something else does. next you can try to see which of them, e.g. `vmInfo.compressed`, etc

Comment: Thanks @KirilS. the ```vmInfo.phys_footprint``` is exactly what I was looking for!